# How to enable MUC/Sub model in ejabberd 16.09?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I installed ejabberd 16.09. But, How to enable muc/sub model in ejabberd yml file? Is this feature available in ejabberd community addition?

I am sending stanza like

```
<iq from='sam@localhost'
to='test@conference.localhost'
type='get'
id='ik3vs715'>
<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>
</iq>
```

but i am not getting responcse like

```
<feature var="urn:xmpp:mucsub:0" />
```

please reply

Answer (score 0):

You should query [room configuration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roomconfig) and check "enable subscription" option

Comment: Is there any option in ejabberd.yml to enable muc_sub option?

Comment: Hey finally i got success with the configuration in ejabberd.yml                                                                     `default_room_options:
     persistent: true allow_subscription:true`                                                                              now i successfully subscribe for event in muc room. not problem is how i can check event messages from muc room with pidgin xmpp console.